# Different textures

Tags: mesh

I can't figure it out, I have 2 rims, with as far as I know the same assigned texture and yet they are not equal.
How is that possible, what am I overlooking?

On the right you can clearly see the scratches and on the left you don't, the left one is smooth, but I also want to see the "scratches" in the left.

[image]

Comment: maybe each one has a different UV map? you can share your file here (share the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/  don't forget to pack the images

Comment: I took a look and you are right, it depends on how the UV map is made, the difference in rotation of the mesh determines the UV map.
Thank you very much, great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each object has a different UV map, so it gives a different result for each one. Make sure they have the same UV map.